# Android: Camera is not available problem

Tags: android, camera, capture

I am trying to capture video and the routine throws an exception when the execution reaches recorder.prepare() statement:

```
private void recordVideoStart(){
    if(recorder != null)
    {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
    }
    File file = new File("/sdcard/videoTest.3gpp");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    recorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
    //recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(videoPreview.getSurface());

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recorder.start();
}
```

Looking the LogCat I noticed the line "Camera is not available".

Does anyone know what could be wrong here and how to enable video capture?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using emulator or device?

Comment: I'm using a device (HTC Dream G1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the a Camera to the recorder.

```
recorder.setCamera(Camera.open());
```

Answer (score 0):

have you added in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following permissions are there in your manifest.
`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is required for it to write onto our SD card

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```